# Update existing legend that contains a PolyCollection

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, legend

Before going to the [`PolyCollection`](https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection) issue, I'm already curious if there's a concise way for adding a new element to an existing legend in general. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.legend(handles=ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], '-', label='foo'))
p, = ax.plot([1, 2], [1, 2], '--o', label='bar')
```

Now I would like to add `p` to the existing legend `ax.get_legend()`. I found I can do (though  it's not really *updating*):

```
ax.legend(handles=ax.get_legend().legendHandles + [p])
```

I feel there should exist a cleaner way. Does it?

[image: Example 1]

But when the legend contains a `PolyCollection` the corresponding label gets lost:

```
ax.legend(handles=[ax.fill_between([0, 1], 0, 1, color='green', label='foo')])
p = ax.fill_between([1, 2], 0, 1, color='orange', label='bar')
ax.legend(handles=ax.get_legend().legendHandles + [p])
```

[image: Example 2]

Now I was looking for a way to retrieve the labels that are stored inside the legend, however no luck, `dir(ax.get_legend())` didn't reveal anything helpful. Interestingly the corresponding `handle` doesn't know its label either (though it does for the first example with `plot`):

```
ax.get_legend().legendHandles[0].get_label()  # Empty string.
```

So I wonder how the legend knows at all which label corresponds to that handle; it must be stored somewhere inside the legend object.

**And my central question:** How can I update the existing legend with a new item, without loosing any of the previous information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not update a legend. Instead you just create it after your plots.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

p1 = ax.fill_between([0, 1], 0, 1, color='green', label='foo')
p2 = ax.fill_between([1, 2], 0, 1, color='orange', label='bar')

ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

If it happens that a plot is created later (e.g. via interactive use or an animation) you still just call `legend` again.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

p1 = ax.fill_between([0, 1], 0, 1, color='green', label='foo')
ax.legend()

p2 = ax.fill_between([1, 2], 0, 1, color='orange', label='bar')
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```